# simplexml взять название бренда

Tags: php, simplexml

Добрый вечер. 
Такая проблема есть товар в xml и в нем есть id категории и бренда - http://joxi.ru/VrwoZ1ecODYo7r
Вот все лежит в начале файла http://joxi.ru/EA4NVEbswYNXpm 
как вытащить название **правильней** вытащить и поместить в $yml_offer['brand'] = implode(xml2array($category->brand));

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('products.xml');

function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
{
    foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
        $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

    return $out;
}
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$articles = [];
foreach ($xml->xpath('/market') as $element) {

   echo "<pre>";
    print_r(xml2array($element->brands));
   echo "</pre>";


    foreach ($element->xpath('products/product') as $category) {

        $yml_offer = array();

            $yml_offer['name'] = implode(xml2array($category->name));
            $yml_offer['price'] = implode(xml2array($category->price));
            $yml_offer['upc'] = implode(xml2array($category->upc));
            $yml_offer['brand'] = implode(xml2array($category->brand));
            $yml_offer['subcategory'] = implode(xml2array($category->subcategory));
            $yml_offer['pictures'] = '';
            foreach (xml2array($category->images) as $pictures){
                $yml_offer['pictures'].= $pictures.',';
            }
            $pics = explode(",",$yml_offer['pictures']);
            $yml_offer['picture'] = $pics[0];
            $yml_offer['pictures'] = trim(str_replace($yml_offer['picture'],'',$yml_offer['pictures']),',');

            $yml_offer['provider'] = 'start1.ru';
            $articles[] = $yml_offer;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Изображения нужно вставлять через [специальную кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) на `stack.imgur.com`. Рисунок с вашего хостинга удалят через 90 дней, это недопустимо, так на `stack.imgur.com` он будет хранится постоянно. Но вообще код можно текстом вставлять.

Comment: 1. Вытащить заранее все бренды с ключом id и названием в качестве значения. 2. Проверять на существование `if(isset($brands[implode(xml2array($category->brand))]))` и, если существует, вставлять его значение

Comment: @DaemonHK немного не пойму как вытащить в этом и проблема